# Insert the CSV data into Elasticsearch in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch
I want to insert the bulk data from the CSV to Elasticsearch
and my code is:

```
class MyEncoder1(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj,datetime.date):
            obj= datetime.strptime(obj,"%Y-%m-%d ")
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            obj= datetime.strptime(obj,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.time):
            obj = datetime.time.strftime(obj,"%H:%M:%S")
        elif isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            obj = float(obj)
        else:
            obj = super(MyEncoder1, self).default(obj)
        return obj
```

Function to write data:

```
def elastic():
    FILE = "C:\\Users\\home\\Downloads\\elasticsearch-6.2.3\\test.csv"
    ES_HOST = {
    "host" : "localhost", 
    "port" : 9200
    }
    INDEX_NAME = 'listusers'
    TYPE_NAME = 'users'
    ID_FIELD = 'id'
    f = open(FILE, 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header=["id","title"]
    bulk_data = [] 
    for row in reader:
        data_dict = {}
        for i in range(len(row)):
            data_dict[header[i]] = row[i]
            print(data_dict)
        op_dict = {"index": {
                    "_index": INDEX_NAME, 
                    "_type": TYPE_NAME, 
                    "_id": data_dict[ID_FIELD]}}

        bulk_data.append(op_dict)
        bulk_data.append(data_dict)

    json_array  = dumps(bulk_data,cls=MyEncoder1)
    request_body = {
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0
    }}
    es = Elasticsearch(hosts = [ES_HOST])
    ##print("creating '%s' index..." % (INDEX_NAME))
    res = es.indices.create(index = INDEX_NAME, body = request_body)
    print(" response: '%s'" % (res))
##res = es.bulk(index = INDEX_NAME, body = json_array, refresh = True)
```

And the JSON array output is:

```
[{"index": {"_type": "users", "_index": "listusers", "_id": "1"}}, {"title": "I am in india", "id": "1"}, {"index": {"_type": "users", "_index": "listusers", "_id": "2"}}, {"title": "I am in america", "id": "2"}, {"index": {"_type": "users", "_index": "listusers", "_id": "3"}}, {"title": "I am in japan", "id": "3"}]
```

And the error I am getting is:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(406, 'Content-Type header [] is not supported')

Comment: In this way, we can't understand. You have commented your bulk ingestion. In which line the error is raised?

Comment: HEAD /listusers [status:404 request:0.254s]
PUT /listusers [status:406 request:0.006s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    res = es.indices.create(index = INDEX_NAME, body = request_body)
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(406, 'Content-Type header [] is not supported')                                                 i am getting the error at creating the indexes @ Lupanoide

Comment: Could you check if your are running the same version of the python library and elasticsearch server?

Comment: i am using pyhton 3.5.2 and elsticsearch 6.2.3

Comment: No, you should know the version of the es python library. Could you post the output of pip freeze | grep  elasticsearch ?